# Can I convert markdown file to emacs org file?

Tags: emacs

I can use `org-md-export-to-markdown`, make md to org.

but I want to convert markdown file to emacs org file, any tools ?

Comment: Try [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's the [Pandoc](http://pandoc.org/) command to convert from the command line:

```
pandoc -f markdown -t org -o newfile.org original-file.markdown
```

From [This question on the Emacs Stack Exchange](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/5465/how-to-migrate-markdown-files-to-emacs-org-mode-format/5467#5467%22This%20question%22.).

Comment: this answer should be accpeted